# Neutral element product group scheme

Tags: tensor-products, group-schemes

Let $G=Spec(A)$ be an affine group scheme over $Spec(k)$ with $k$ a field.
The neutral of $G$ is an element $e\in |G|$, which is the image of the zero ideal by the continuous map:
$|Spec(k)|\rightarrow |G|$. Let write it $e:=p \in Spec(A)$

Let have a look at $G\times G$. This is also a $k$-affine scheme, $G\times G=Spec(A\otimes A)$.
I am looking for its neutral element. As above, it is the image of the zero ideal by the continuous map: $|Spec(k)|\rightarrow |G\times G|$.

What is it ? I don't know how to find it.

Comment: If $m$ is the ideal of $A$ corresponding to the neutral element of $G$, the ideal of $A \otimes A$ corresponding to the neutral element of $G \times G$ is $m \otimes A+A \otimes m$.

Comment: I actually don't get really why ?

Comment: Because through the two projections $G \times G \rightarrow G$, (ie the two inclusions $A \rightarrow A \otimes A$) the neutral element projects to (resp. the associated ideal is pulled back to) the neutral element of $G$ (resp. the corresponding maximum ideal of $A$).

Comment: Ok this is actually very easy.. Thanks !!